# How to style an Image for auto-height in NextJS / nextra

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-image

I have a [nextjs based application using nextra](https://github.com/vercel/nextjs-portfolio-starter).

I want to put images into a blog post with a **fixed width** but an automatically calculated height. How to do that?

This is my markdown, rendered by the nextra-library using `next/image`-component:

```
---
type: page
title: Photos
date: 2021-03-18
---

# Photos

Here's some of my photography.

import Image from 'next/image'


<Image
  src="/photos/test.png"
  alt="Photo"
  width={200}
  priority
  className="next-image"
/>
```

This will return the error message:

> Error: Image with src "/photos/test.jpg" must use "width" and "height"
> properties or "layout='fill'" property.

The property "layout=fill" doesn't work either, as it stretches the image over the full screen size.

Any ideas on how to do that?